# First proof over Reals in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm new to Coq. I've been working through [Pierce's Logical Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/index.html). I'm stepping out-of-scope of the text into Real numbers and finding myself clueless. I thought I'd prove something easy so I wrote out some formulas for interest calculations. Now I'd like to prove my conversions are correctly written in my Theorem.

I have no idea how to proceed and am in need of hints and guides!!!

```
From Coq Require Import Reals.Reals. 

Definition simple_compound (A r n m : R) : R :=
  A * (Rpower (1 + r / m) (m * n)). 
Definition continuous_compound (A r n: R) : R :=
  A * (exp (r * n)).

Definition simple_to_continuous_interest (Rm n m: R) : R :=
  m * ln (1 + Rm). 

Definition continuous_to_simple_interest (Rc n m: R) : R :=
  m * (exp (Rc / m) - 1). 

(** Prove that given Rm n m, then Rc is m * ln (1 + Rm). *)

Theorem continuous_to_simple_works : forall (A Rc n m : R),
  continuous_compound A Rc n = simple_compound A (continuous_to_simple_interest Rc n m) n m. 
Proof.
  intros A Rc n m.
  unfold continuous_compound. unfold simple_compound. unfold continuous_to_simple_interest.
  simpl. (** ... and I'm stuck. I would know how to do this algebraically but am clueless in Coq. *)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest to unfold `Rpower`.

Second, a useful lemma is `f_equal`; it states that, to prove `f a = f b`, it suffices to prove `a = b`. (There is also a tactic with the exact same name, which will behave similarly.)

Third, you need to perform some algebraic simplifications. To do so, you can use `replace foo with bar`; as the name implies, it replaces all the occurrences of `foo` in the goal with `bar` and it requires you to prove `bar = foo`. This latter equality can then be discharged with the `field` tactic, which checks that two expressions are equal by using the rewriting rules of addition, multiplication, division.

Fourth, you should end up with a goal containing a subterm `ln (exp baz)`. Obviously, you want to replace it with `baz`. You can use the command `Search (ln (exp _))` to find the name of the corresponding lemma. It happens to be named `ln_exp`, so `rewrite ln_exp` will do the trick.

Comment: you the man! I failed at a few uses of `field` and don't know why. I asked a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62922088/coq-field-tactic-fails-to-simplify-yeilds-m-0r