# coq field tactic fails to simplify, yeilds "m <> 0%R"

Tags: coq

I'm new to Coq. I've been working through [Pierce's Logical Foundations](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/ring.html). I'm stepping into new ground.

I'm trying use of the `field` tactic for the first time. I use it thrice in the below theorem. Twice it fails, yielding `m <> 0%R` where m is a term in context.

I'm sure I just fail to understand proper use. May someone enlighten me? (I tried reading [this doc page](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/ring.html) but didn't gain much understanding!)

```
From Coq Require Import Reals.Reals. 
Require Import Field.

Definition simple_compound (A r n m : R) : R :=
  A * (Rpower (1 + r / m) (m * n)). 
Definition continuous_compound (A r n: R) : R :=
  A * (exp (r * n)).
Definition simple_to_continuous_interest (Rs n m: R) : R :=
  m * ln (1 + Rs / m). 
Definition continuous_to_simple_interest (Rc n m: R) : R :=
  m * ((exp (Rc / m)) - 1). 

Theorem continuous_to_simple_works : forall (A Rc n m : R),
  continuous_compound A Rc n = simple_compound A (continuous_to_simple_interest Rc n m) n m. 
Proof.
  intros A Rc n m.
  unfold continuous_compound. unfold simple_compound. unfold continuous_to_simple_interest.
  unfold Rpower. apply f_equal.
  assert (H: (m * (exp (Rc / m) - 1) / m)%R = (exp (Rc / m) - 1)%R). {
    field. admit.
  }
  rewrite -> H. 
  assert (H2: (1 + (exp (Rc / m) - 1))%R = (exp (Rc / m))%R). {
    field. 
  }
  rewrite -> H2. 
  assert (H3: (m * n * ln (exp (Rc / m)))%R = (ln (exp (Rc / m)) * m * n)%R). {
    rewrite -> Rmult_comm. rewrite -> Rmult_assoc. reflexivity. 
  }
  rewrite -> H3. 
  rewrite -> ln_exp. 
  assert (H4: (Rc / m * m)%R = Rc%R). {
    field. admit. 
  }
  rewrite -> H4. 
  reflexivity. 
Admitted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected. Your first use of `field` is on a goal akin to `(m * x) / m = x`. There is absolutely no way of defining the division over real numbers so that this equality holds for all real numbers `x` when `m` is equal to `0`. So, the `field` tactic is able to prove this equality only if you are able to prove `m <> 0`. Your third use of `field` is on an equality `(x / m) * m = x`, and again, it can only hold for any `x` if you know that `m` is nonzero.

Comment: Ahhh... that's rather obvious in a way but I likely would've bottomed trying to deduce that myself from the message!

Comment: Further it looks like Positive Reals don't exist in the Coq standard library as-is so I'll try hacking such a type...